# Feature Request: Notifications for question answers

Tags: feature-request

I often come across interesting new questions which don't have any answers yet. To further my knowledge, I would like to revisit these questions when they do have answers.

I would absolutely love it if a feature could be implemented where one "subscribes" to a question and gets some type of notification when either the question is answered, or an answer is accepted.

These notifications could form part of the other notifications in your inbox.

What I do at the moment is "favorite" questions with the hopes of (a) remembering to look at questions that I've previously "favorited" and (b) that the questions do in fact have an answer now.

I think such a feature could go a long way in promoting learning and knowledge sharing over and above the questions that you ask yourself.

Would love to hear what the community thinks of this.

Comment: When I started participating in SE, I initially thought that the *favorite* feature was doing that. I've been disappointed too. Anyway, maybe it would be worth bringing this to the main meta site, this could be useful to any other site, not just EE.SE.

Comment: In the mean time this feature has been implemented: [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network)

Answer (score -4):

There is already a way to do that. Simply press the star button underneath the voting buttons to mark it a favorite. You can then go to your profile and keep tabs on it.

If you wish to receive notifications on a question, make a comment below the post and you will monitor the conversation that is in the post with exception to comments directed to specific users.

It is not likely that you will get a feature change as this takes time and effort from the SE programmers and they have bigger fish to fry.

Comment: Did you not read the question?

Comment: I don't believe you're notified on comments to q or a that don't belong to you unless you're specified with an @.  Further, consider the long list of "following" comments that this might generate.